# How to convert array variable from trigger to javascript array in dynaform panel?

Tags: processmaker

In Processmaker 3 I use Trigger to query the database and store the result in Array.

I want to use this array in Dynaform panel control as a Javascript array so I can display it using Javascript.

How I can Convert it from normal PHP array to javascript array?

I attempted to use JSON convert functions but it never worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hidden : https://forum.processmaker.com/viewtopic.php?t=437
in a trigger pass @=hiddenFieldName to result of query
then use hiddenFieldName value with : 

`$('#hiddenFieldName').getValue()`